# Firebase Cloud Function - Triggering Expo SDK to Push Notifications to Users

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, expo

I am working on an app based of Expo - I decided to use firebase as a backend but had come up to a blocker, I need to send push notifications to the users in the app - but Expo doesn't work with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) unless I eject the Expo project and work independently with Android and ios.

To overcome this I decided to store the Expo Notification Tokens in firebase and then write a firebase cloud function in firebase to get all these tokens from the database and trigger a sendPushNotificationAsync() using the expo-server-sdk.

I understand that to do this approach my version of firebase cannot be on the Spark plan - and it isn't.

I decided to implement the solution in TypeScript so I can conform to ES6/ES7 coding standards.

The approach is - I trigger a get request to my firebase function url and this triggers the function to execute. With the code below - when I do a get request against the provided google function URL I get an error:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user 
>       callback. TypeError: expo.isExpoPushToken is not a function
>       at admin.database.ref.once (/user_code/lib/index.js:24:18)
>       at onceCallback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-

Is there something I am doing incorrectly it doesn't seem like it is able to initialise and use functions from the Expo import, although I have included this in the package.json to be installed, imported and used.

index.ts - generated by firebase

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as Expo from 'expo-server-sdk';

admin.initializeApp();
// Create a new Expo SDK client
let expo = new Expo();

exports.pushNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
  if(req.method !== 'GET'){
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!')
  }

  let allTokens = [];
  let messages = [];

  admin.database().ref('/all_user_push_tokens/').once('value', (snapshot) => {
    if(expo.isExpoPushToken(snapshot.val())){
      allTokens.push(snapshot.val())
    } else {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    for (var token in allTokens){
      messages.push({
        to: token,
        sound: 'default',
        title: 'NXET',
        body: ' NEW ACTIVITIES ADDED!'
      })
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages)

    async (chunks) => {
      for (let chunk of chunks) {
        try {
          await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
        } catch (error){
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    }

    return res.status(200).send('SUCCESS - NOTIFICATIONS SENT!!')

  })
  .catch(() => {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!')
  });

  return res.status(200).send('Function Executing')

})
```

package.json

```
{

"name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-server-sdk": "^2.3.3",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking quickly at the Expo server sdk, it looks like `isExpoPushToken` is a class method rather than an instance method, thus you should be calling the method on the class `Expo` than the instance `expo` (notice uppercase vs. lowercase).

From the [Expo server sdk github page](https://github.com/expo/exponent-server-sdk-node):

```
// Check that all your push tokens appear to be valid Expo push tokens
if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
  console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
  continue;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue I was facing - Thank you for the response! Apparently this is an issue a lot of people using Expo with a firebase backend are having - I'm thinking of writing my little cloud function for sending Expo notification somewhere on Medium - thanks again! :D